# Site-to-Site VPN between Web App + Azure VM within VNET & on-prem VLAN possible?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, azure-vpn

Is it possible to establish a Site-to-Site VPN between Web App and Azure VM within VNET & on-prem VLAN so that servers on Azure & on-premise can talk with each other as if they are on the same network?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the general configuration to achieve that would be the following:
1. VNet intergation between Azure WebApp and Azure VM's VNet
2. Site-to-Site VPN between on-prem and Azure VNet

[image]

Usefull link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet